# How can I apply function `max` to a list of numbers?

Tags: list, arguments, apply

I want to find the max element in a list of numbers.

```
(setq l (list 1 2 3 4 5))
```

What is an easy way to call the `max` function on `l`?
So far I have this but this seems convoluted:

```
(eval `(max ,@l))
```

It seems like there should be an easier way. No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `apply` is what you're looking for:

```lisp
(apply #'max l)
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I am looking for! Thank you.